# Accordion script not working with barba.js

Tags: accordion, barbajs

Here is the basic code:

```
<body>
<div id="barba-wrapper" class="main">
    <div class="barba-container">

        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accord-header">link</div>
            <div class="accord-content">content</div>
        </div>

        <script src="/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/barba.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/scripts.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {
            // for active header definition
            $('.accord-header').removeClass('on');
            $(this).addClass('on');
            // accordion actions
            if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
                $(this).next("div").slideUp(300);
                $(this).removeClass('on');
            } else {
                $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp(300);
                $(this).next("div").slideToggle(300);
            }
        });
        </script>

    </div><!-- barba-wrapper -->
</div><!-- barba-container -->
</body>
```

The issue is that the first time the page is loaded, the accordion works fine. But when you go to another page and then come back, the script is no longer working. I tried adding to the end of scripts.js:

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {
    eval(container.querySelector("script").innerHTML);
});
```

As they suggest but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

solved. The issue was where I was putting it. Instead of putting it at the end of the barba script I added this right before:

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('transitionCompleted', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {

            $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {
                // for active header definition
                $('.accord-header').removeClass('on');
                $(this).addClass('on');
                // accordion actions
                if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
                    $(this).next("div").slideUp(300);
                    $(this).removeClass('on');
                } else {
                    $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp(300);
                    $(this).next("div").slideToggle(300);
                }
            });

        });

    });

}(Barba, jQuery));
```

The important part is that it was added before the

```
}(Barba, jQuery));
```

that was already there to end the original code, not after that.